# redirect visitor to another ccTLD based on location but stays on same page/requested URL - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, geolocation, e-commerce

I was running my store on .com domain. I decided to copy it on .co.uk domain to manage both separately for UK & USA customers.

Now I wanted to create redirects based on customer IP, if customer is visiting (example.com/product/ankle-strap) from UK, it should redirect him to UK version of that page, like:(example.co.uk/product/ankle-strap).

Everyone is giving solution about a static URL redirecct where visitor visiting to example.com from UK will be redirect to example.co.uk, this works only for homepages or any specific page set by us.

which is not a complete solution for an online store as ecommerce stores have 100's of pages and we cannot set all them one by one. I wanted it to work dynamically.